# Templates and Array of structs that contain pointer to method in class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, struct

I am trying to create a class that defines an array of command structs, each of which has two CHAR variables, one CHAR*, one INT and a pointer to a void function that accepts two CHAR arguments. There will be multiple instances of this array, each in a different class. I feel like I am close, but missing something critical. The Arduino GNU compiler seems to agree that I am missing something. Here's the code (with modifications as per Bo R);

```
<<<<<<<<<< Commands.h >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

#pragma once
//template <class T>
class Commands {
public:
    typedef void ( Commands::*FunctionPointer )( char, char );

    struct command {
        char sel;
        char act;
        char const *desc;
        FunctionPointer funcPtr;
    };

    command myCommands [2] = {
        command { 'a','?',"FOO", &Commands::foo },
        command { 'b','x',"BAR", &Commands::bar },
    };

    int cmdSize = sizeof ( myCommands ) / sizeof ( myCommands [0] );

    void foo ( char sel, char act ) {
        show ( { sel }, { act } );
    }

    void bar ( char sel, char act ) {
        show ( { sel }, { act } );
    }

    void show ( char sel, char act ) {
        Serial.print ( "SEL = " );
        Serial.print ( sel );
        Serial.print ( " ACT = " );
        Serial.println ( act );
    }

    void execute ( char sel, char act ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cmdSize; i++) {
            if (myCommands [i].sel == sel && myCommands [i].act == act) {
                Serial.println ( myCommands [i].desc );
                ( this->*myCommands [i].funcPtr )( sel, act );
                return;
            }
        }
        Serial.print ( F ( "Unknown SEL/ACT Pair:" ) );
        Serial.print ( sel );
        Serial.print ( '/' );
        Serial.println ( act );
    }
};


<<<<<<<<<< StructArray.ino >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

#include "Commands.h"    
Commands cmd;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin ( 115200 );
    Serial.println ( "EXECUTING:" );
    cmd.execute ( 'a', '?' );
    cmd.execute ( 'b', '?' );
    cmd.execute ( 'b', 'x' );
    Serial.println ( "DONE" );
}

void loop(){}
```

If I refactor Commands into Template.h and Foo.h (as below), I get four compile errors that I don't understand how to fix:

Severity    Code    Description File    Line
Error       error: invalid use of template-name 'Template' without an argument list D:\Documents\Arduino\StructArray\Foo.h  6
Error       error: 'myCommands' was not declared in this scope  D:\Documents\Arduino\StructArray\Foo.h  11
Error       error: 'myCommands' was not declared in this scope  D:\Documents\Arduino\StructArray\Foo.h  11
Error       error: invalid use of template-name 'Foo' without an argument list  D:\Documents\Arduino\StructArray\StructArray.ino    7

Here is the code for Template.h:

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class Template {
public:
    typedef void ( T::*FunctionPointer )( char, char );

    struct command {
        char sel;
        char act;
        char const *desc;
        FunctionPointer funcPtr;
    };

    void show ( char sel, char act ) {
        Serial.print ( "SEL = " );
        Serial.print ( sel );
        Serial.print ( " ACT = " );
        Serial.println ( act );
    }

    void execute ( char sel, char act, int cmdSize ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cmdSize; i++) {
            if (T::myCommands[i].sel == sel && T::myCommands [i].act == act) {
                Serial.println ( T::myCommands [i].desc );
                ( this->*T::myCommands [i].funcPtr )( sel, act );
                return;
            }
        }
        Serial.print ( F ( "Unknown SEL/ACT Pair:" ) );
        Serial.print ( sel );
        Serial.print ( '/' );
        Serial.println ( act );
    }
};
```

And Foo.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Template.h"
template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
    Template::command myCommands [2] = {
    command { 'a','?',"FOO-A", &Foo::foo },
    command { 'b','x',"FOO-B", &Foo::bar },
    };

    int cmdSize = sizeof ( myCommands ) / sizeof ( myCommands [0] );


    void foo ( char sel, char act ) {
        show ( { sel }, { act } );
    }

    void bar ( char sel, char act ) {
        show ( { sel }, { act } );
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: #pragma once is only available to msvc, last i bothered to check many years ago.

Comment: Did you mean `FunctionPointer  f;` instead of `void ( *FunctionPointer )( char, char );` ?

Answer (score 1):

If I start you out on the non-templated version, you will see that you need to make some changes.

```
class Commands {
public:
    typedef void ( Commands::*FunctionPointer )( char, char );

    struct command {
        char sel;
        char act;
        char const *desc;
        FunctionPointer funcPtr;
    };

    command myCommands [2] = {
            { 'a','?',"FOO", &Commands::foo },
            { 'b','x',"BAR", &Commands::bar }
    };

    int cmdSize = sizeof ( this->myCommands ) / sizeof ( this->myCommands [0] );

    void foo ( char sel, char act ) {
        char buf[2] = {sel};
        Serial.println ( buf );
    }

    void bar ( char sel, char act ) {
        char buf[2] = { sel };
        Serial.println ( buf );
    }

    void execute ( char sel, char act ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cmdSize; i++) {
            if (myCommands [i].sel == sel && myCommands [i].act == act) {
                Serial.println ( myCommands [i].desc );
                (this->*myCommands [i].funcPtr)( sel, act );
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Once that is solved you can attack the templating (which I didn't see the purpose right now in this example since the foo and bar were part of the template class.)

Comment: My goal is to have the typedef, the Command struct definition, the execute and show methods in a single class and to have multiple classes, each with its own set of commands and command handling functions, but I am still trying to GROK Templates and am missing some important details, as shown by the compiler error messages.